# Trying to import utils/atoms in react native

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the error 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../utils/atoms'', and have already tried npm install utils. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please add more information like

- code you have written
- packages you have installed
- package-name like component a library you think this error is coming from
- full error message you have received

With this amount of information my best guess would be, to check if you import a component from the path '../utils/atoms'. Maybe you forgot to update an import-statement after removing/moving a component in your project.